# Stretch Background for View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8.1

I am using adding Background in iOS Swift App using:

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
```

However, it does not cover the Screen till bottom. I searched Other questions:

```
var backImage = UIImage(named: "background")

var resizablebackImage = backImage?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top:10,left:0,bottom:10,right:0))

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:resizablebackImage!)
```

That does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the screen shot of your view ?

Comment: @BharatJagtap http://postimg.org/image/burcaxosv/

Comment: If you want to set that image as background image don't convert it to patternimage and set it as backgrouncolor

Comment: @MidhunMP and How do I do that?

Comment: @user2078462: Hope it is working

Comment: @MidhunMP Working on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to set it as the background image, don't make image as pattern color and fill it as background color. Instead create an `UIImageView` set your image as it's image and add it to your `UIView`.

```
var bgImage     = UIImage(named: "background");
var imageView   = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds);
imageView.image = bgImage
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

Comment: what if the content is overlapped by the image? (i.e. buttons...)

Comment: @MaRco85: That' why we are adding the image as inner most child view. Check the code `self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)`

Answer (score 1):

### For Swift 1.x & Swift 2 plus Device Rotation Detection

Please see my code below. Just set `bgImageName` to the name of your image and call `setBackgroundImage()`. I added an auto-reload in case of a device rotation.

```
var bgImage = UIImage()
var bgImageView = UIImageView()
var bgImageName = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bgImageName = "bg-orange" // or whatever your image is called
    setBackgroundImage()
}

func setBackgroundImage() {
    if bgImageName > "" {
        bgImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        bgImage = UIImage(named: bgImageName)!
        bgImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        bgImageView.image = bgImage
        self.view.addSubview(bgImageView)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(bgImageView)
    }
}

// detect device orientation changes
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("rotated device to landscape")
        setBackgroundImage()
    } else {
        print("rotated device to portrait")
        setBackgroundImage()
    }
}
```